# Array destructuring in function parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have something here related to array destructuring that I don't fully understand.

In the following example:

```
function foo( [a, b, c] ) {
    console.log(a, b, c)
}

foo( 1, 2, 3 );
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Now, I am not questioning the fact that this doesn't output `1, 2, 3` as one might expect since only the first value `1` actually get destructured (`a = 1[0], b = 1[1], c = 1[2]`).

But here's the thing:

I can perfectly write `1[0], 1[1], 1[2]` and I get `undefined` for each of those.

Then why the `foo` function I wrote above throws an exception instead of simply returning 3 times `undefined` as I'd expect.

Indeed, if I write `bar` as following, I am getting 3 `undefined` as should happen.

```
function bar() {
    console.log( 1[0], 1[1], 1[2] )
}

bar();
// undefined undefined undefined
```

Can someone tell me what JS does in the first `foo()` and why the output it's not `undefined undefined undefined`?

Comment: I've not seen destructuring done in this way; are you able to point to some documentation on how this kind of destructuring works?

Comment: @tommyO No. The syntax should be correct. Indeed, by passing foo( [1, 2, 3] ). It gets properly deconstructed and properly assigned.

Comment: @OliverRadini I couldn't find on MDN. Have a look at: http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html

Comment: The problem is that `Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` is undefined. Not that I recommend it but If you do `Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){}` it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destructuring with an array pattern uses iteration in the background, i.e. the value being destructured must be iterable.

In fact, in Firefox, the error message seems more indicative:

> TypeError: (destructured parameter) is not iterable

That is where the comparison you make with evaluating `1[0], 1[1], 1[2]` goes wrong: that does not need `1` to be iterable.

A more correct comparison would be to do this:

```js
console.log([...1]);
// or:
const [a, b, c] = 1;
```

...and that code will fail.

Answer (score 5):

Array destructuring is actually [Iterator Destructuring](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2018/#sec-runtime-semantics-iteratordestructuringassignmentevaluation) that works with anything implementing `Symbol.iterator` method.

For example

```js
function foo([a, b, c]) {
  console.log([a, b, c])
}

foo({
  * [Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  }
})
```

`Number` doesn't implement iterator protocol

```js
console.log(1[Symbol.iterator])
```

That's why you get the error.

But if you implement it (**NOT RECOMMENDED**)

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  yield * this.toString(2); // just an example
}

function foo([a, b,c]) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

foo(6)
```

Comment: I think you somehow destructured the second word in your answer :-P

Comment: @trincot LOL :)

Comment: Thanks, @YuryTarabanko. (Now) Totally makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the function `foo()` can only accept `iterables`. See the below given example:

```js
function foo( [a, b, c] ) {
    console.log(a, b, c)
}

foo( [4, 5, 6] );  // works okay

foo( 3,4,5 ); // undefined is not a function
```

IMHO, [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is used as a gatherer in these type of scenarios like this:

```js
function foo( ...[a, b, c] ) {
    console.log(a, b, c)
}

foo( ...[4, 5, 'v'] );  //works fine

foo(1,3,4); // also works fine
```

> Why foo() throws an exception?

That's because of incompatible parameters (b/w caller & calee) which has nothing to do with the fact that in JavaScript `1[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: "This happens because the function foo() can only accept array or destructured array" This is actually not true.

Comment: @leonardofed can it accept other values than `array`? (Updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The function `foo()` is completely different with `bar()` due to the fact that `1` is a valid number in javascript and trying to access `1[0]` is `undefined` as it looks for the index `0` of value `1` which is surely `undefined`. That is why you get three `undefined` for `1[0], 1[1], 1[2]`

Now, the single `undefined` from `foo()` is not from `console.log()` but it is from the error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

As your function signature is incorrect. To use it in proper way you can use spread syntax:

```js
function foo(...arg) {
    console.log(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);
}

foo( 1, 2, 3 );
```

Comment: You didn't answer my question. The question is not, why does bar() output undefined, but why does foo() throw an exception.

Please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

It's because function `foo` is expecting an array/string so he can destruct it.

Since you're not passing anything it causes the destruction to fail, this is like doing

```
var arrayVariable = undefined
var [a, b, c] = arrayVariable // this will throw an error
var d = arrayVariable['a'] // this will throw an error
```

So to avoid throwing an error, provide an array argument

```
foo('') // undefined, undefined, undefined
foo('123') // 1, 2, 3
foo([]); // undefined, undefined, undefined
foo([1, 2, 3]) // 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: " function foo is expecting an array " nope. Try `foo('abc')`

Comment: "It's because function foo is expecting an array/string (something that you can access with prop[value])" yet again nope. Try `foo({})`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. What I meant was something that you can access with `property[value]`

Comment: Yes but you obviosly can access empty object's props. :)

Comment: *"It's because function foo is expecting an array/string so he can destruct it."*: it does not necessarily have to be an array or string.

Comment: > Try foo({})

{} object is not an iterable, so this would raise an error just like passing a single number. If you'd like to foo({}), you should deconstruct with an obj pattern, not an array pattern.

ie. 

`function foo( {a, b, c} ) {
    console.log(a, b, c)
}

foo( {} );`

/cc @YuryTarabanko